# Circular animation doesn't play

Tags: android, animation, kotlin

I'm trying to run Circular reveal animation on my view. I've some experience with this on the other project, but now I can't launch this code.

```
private fun openRevealView() {

    val animatedView = activity.findViewById(R.id.a_view);
    animatedView.visibility = View.VISIBLE

    var cx = (animatedView.getLeft() + animatedView.getRight()) / 2;
    var cy = (animatedView.getTop() + animatedView.getBottom()) / 2;

    val finalRadius = Math.max(animatedView.height, animatedView.width)
    val anim = ViewAnimationUtils
            .createCircularReveal(animatedView, cx, cy,
                    0.toFloat(),
                    finalRadius.toFloat())

    Ln.i("Reveal animation params ["
            + animatedView.height
            + " " + animatedView.width
            + ", 0, " + finalRadius + "]")
    anim.start()
}
```

Layout is:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dip"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <android.support.v4.app.FragmentTabHost
            android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <View
        android:id="@+id/a_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/app.red"
        android:visibility="invisible" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Log is:

> Reveal animation params [153 114, 0, 1134]

and everything looks good, but there is no animation, just simple Visible/Invisible actions. 
Also I tried to add listener, so it worked well too.
I've my other project with code like that and it works like sharm on the same phone.

My android config is

> compileSdkVersion 23 
>   buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"

Thanks for any help.

*It's Kotlin code. but it's not a problem, I couldn't start animation from any place of my project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so, answer is pretty simple. i had `false` insted of

android:hardwareAccelerated="true"